# Redo Crop Functionality with Fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

**Steps to reproduce**

Working on an image app using Fabric js. One functionality is the ability to crop image and then undo and redo cropping.

**Expected Behavior**

When redo crop is selected, the image should be cropped again.

**Actual Behavior**

When redo crop is selected, the image is not cropped again but the rectangle used to guide the cropping is cropped.

Here is a fiddle to the full code:  http://jsfiddle.net/Da7SP/835/

Below is the redo crop function code.

Can anyone suggest how to overcome this redo crop issue?

Thank you.

```
var redoCrop = function() {
    if(config.redoFinishedStatus){
        if (config.canvasState.length > config.currentStateIndex &&  config.canvasState.length != 0){
            config.redoFinishedStatus = 0;
            config.redoStatus = true;
            canvas.loadFromJSON(config.canvasState[config.currentStateIndex+1], function(){
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(config.canvasState[config.currentStateIndex+1]);
                canvas.renderAll();
                config.redoStatus = false;
                config.currentStateIndex += 1;
                config.redoFinishedStatus = 1;
            });
         }
     }
 }
```